# How do I do this in PHP?

Tags: php

without right-clicking the browser just to view the source, how to display php results as html markup so user can also copy it.

example:

```
$var = 'ipsum'; //user input stored in variable

<p style="align="center">Lorem <?php echo $var; ?> dolor sit amet</p>
```

output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

at the same time, I want to show the html markup so the user can directly copy it without viewing the source like so:

```
<p style="align="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
```

How do I do this in php? appreciate the help. thanks

Comment: Usually you would do this by putting it in a textarea.

Comment: @Brad appreciate if you can show me how the php markup looks like. thanks

Comment: Do you want to display the entire page's source, or just some static markup that never changes?

Comment: So you want the rendered page followed by the source of the rendered page?

Comment: I just want the php result thats wrapped in `<p>` to be shown as html markup. not the whole page source. thanks

Comment: Ok, you can do what is in my answer anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
echo htmlentities('<p style="align="center">Lorem '.$var.' dolor sit amet</p>');
```

or :

```
$var = 'ipsum';
$mark = '<p style="align="center">Lorem '.$var.' dolor sit amet</p>';

echo $mark;
echo htmlentities($mark);
```

Comment: does that mean I have to copy and paste both the code so one will show the actual result and one will show the markup version? thanks

Comment: This doesn't return the page's source--it just displays predetermined markup.

Comment: @mgraph I tried your solution but using `htmlentities` also display the php markup and not the html result of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd put that content into a textarea, then at least its easily selectable:

```
<textarea><p style="align="center">Lorem ipsum <?php echo $var; ?> sit amet</p></textarea>
```

Then you could even use some JavaScript to disable any editing on that textbox and/or 1-click selects all etc.

Oh, another point: Your syntax is invalid.. Not really sure what your trying with your CSS there but I assume it's this:

```
<p style="text-align:center">Lorem ipsum <?php echo $var; ?> sit amet</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `<pre></pre>` html tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use function **ob_start** for buffering output
And use **htmlentities** for automatic convert buffer to "html_code"

Comment: Im still a newbie when it comes to PHP so I would appreciate if you can show me the snippet. thanks

Comment: some examples is in PHP manual for this functions. You can read this http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php and comments. For example `ob_start();
    /* there is your code */
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean(); echo htmlentities($output);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the special values which would be treated as html into their entities.

```
< need to be converted into $lt; 
> need to be converted into $gt; 
etc. .....
```

You can use htmlentities($text); to do this.

Afaik there is no html tag which will do the thing you need.

```
<pre> and <code>
```

does not mean "Don't treat this as html".

Answer (score 0):

Do you you just want to display a certain amount of HTML markup, or do you actually want the entire page's source code, such as you would see when you click "View Source"?

If the latter, you would probably want to do this:

```
<?php
$source= file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo '<textarea>' . htmlentities($source) . '</textarea>';
?>
```

When use use `file_get_contents()` on a URL (assuming a recent version of PHP is installed) it returns that URL's source. Good luck!

Comment: Then @mgraph's answer is the best. :)

Comment: i tried @mgraph solution using `htmlentities` but its displaying the php code on the screen.

Comment: Try using my solution, but change `$source` to what you want displayed... in your case, probably `$source = "<p>Lorem $var dolor sit amet</p>";`

Answer (score -1):

At the start of the php script you can start an output buffer. Then at the bottom of the script you can output twice.

```
<?php
ob_start();
//your php stuff
$contents = ob_get_flush();
echo '<pre>'.$contents.'</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: I see what you're thinking here but it doesn't answer the question.